# Writing a Template Tag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to customise a CMS written in Django. The content editors aren't flexible enough so I'm trying to come up with a better solution.

Without over-explaining it, I'd like it to be a bit like [django-better-chunks](http://bitbucket.org/hakanw/django-better-chunks/wiki/Home) or `django-flatblocks`. You set up an editable region entirely from within the template. I want to bind these editable regions to a mix of strings and object instances. One example would be having multiple editable regions based on one product:

```
{% block product_instance "title" %}
{% block product_instance "product description" %}
```

So if you have a view with another product as `product_instance` those two `blocks` would show different data. I would also see there being use for site-wide blocks that only pass through the string part. Essentially, I would like to be able to pass 1-infinity identifiers.

But I'm really struggling on two fronts here:

1. How do I define the relationship between the mixed identifier and the actual content "`block`" instance? I have a feeling contenttypes might feature here but I've really no idea where to start looking!
2. And how do I write a template tag to read the above syntax and convert that into an object for rendering?

Comment: Will the editable regions sometimes be associated with non-models? That calls for an intermediate model to store the saved data in the database for such strings. Let me know and I'll work up an example when I get home. Sound like a cool idea!

Comment: Ideally you'd throw any combination of objects and strings *but* I don't think that's necessary for my needs. I'll only be using model instances and strings.

Comment: I whipped up an example in your related post. If you find the approach sound I'll try to come up with a good way to deal with this one, too (since they're both related the solution to either is dependent on the other)

Comment: Yeah it's looking good. You stand to make a lot of points =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this you can create an inclusion tag and use it like:

```
{% load my_tags %}
{% product bicycle <extra vars ...> %}
```

To define the tag, add to your app/templatetags/mytags.py:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('results.html')
def product(item, *extra):
    #maybe repackage extra variables
    #and add them to the returned dictionary
    item_form = ItemForm(item) #form.ModelForm instance
    return {'item': item, 'item_form':item_form, ...}
```

Then you'll need a template that returns html for the item:

```
<h1>{{item.title}}</h1>
{{item_form}}
... add some conditional statements depending on extra vars
```