# Conditional tags in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using Django on top of an existing database/user framework so unfortunately it is not possible to me for use the django auth framework.

I have my custom auth library built, now I just need to figure out how to use it in templates. Certain links should only appear for users who have access to it.

In PHP I could do soemthing like this

```
<?php if auth('RestrictedLinkName') {?> <a href=""></a> <?php } ?>
```

What is the Django way? I have been playing with custom tags but haven't been able to get it working yet. I was thinking something like:

```
{% if check_permission('Restrictedarea') %} hjkfgdkhfg  {% endif %}
```

Comment: You're gonna have to provide more information in order to get help. What does your auth backend look like, what is your template context providing you? How do your permissions work?

Comment: Good morning Hedde, first I will explain what I am doing. My application was initialy built on Codeigniter framework and makes use of the Session framework. I am using Django to build a section of the system and am accessing Codeigniter's session information in the database. The check_permission gets the users session ID from a cookie, then queries to find the users details and then check if they have permission based on a restriction table I have which says  'RestrictedAreaName' and then a list of allowed users/groups. Then it returns True or False if the user is within this group or user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your [custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters). But this may help you up to a point, for further, you must write your custom context_processors (and custom [middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/middleware/) if needed.)

But doing authentication and permission check through custom function is quite hard, but possible. I have a system fully runs on custom authentication/authorization.

First of all, you can examine django `context_processors` to understand how they work. then you can write your custom `context_processor`. After you add your context processor in your settings, you can use those methods, and do your authentication/authorization as you wish.

One of my custom `contect_processor` function is like:

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy

def CustomProcessor(request):
    cust_perms = {
        'admin_perm_check': lazy(lambda: myCustomPermChecker(request), myCustomPermChecker)(),
        'system_admin': aFunctionToReturnBoolValue(),
    }
    return custom_perms

class myCustomPermChecker(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def __getitem__(self, perm_name):
        return True if (perm_name in user_perm_list()) else False
```

In your template

```
{%if admin_perm_check.perm_name%}...{%endif%}
{%if system_admin %} this is a bool check{%endif%}
```

You must define your permchecker as a class, which have `__getitem__` method so, your template tag `admin_perm_check.perm_name` could work. This perm checker accepts only one additional paramater (`perm_name`), If you want to use django-style two parameter check then you must do:

```
class myCustomPermChecker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, module_name):
        return SecondPermCheckerStep(module_name)

class SecondPermCheckerStep(object):
    def __init__(self, module_name):
        self.module_name = module_name

    def __getitem__(self, perm_name)
        return True if ('%s.%s' % (self.module_name,perm_name) in user_perm_list()) else False


{%if admin_perm_check.module_name.perm_name%}
```

You can use another `class.__getitem__` to add one more key to tour tag chain in your template etc.

Since your context_processor `CustomProcessor(request):` accept `http.request` object as a parameter, you can pass your methods or functions any value (session id or user id etc.) that will be required in authenticaon or authorization. You can write a middleware to set custom values to your request object to use (like django set `user` instance and let you use `request.user` in your views.). You can also set your custom user model instance so you can use it in you template (if you set it in your request_context) and in your views (if you set it in your middleware)

Reading docs could not help here much, better is checking django code to see how django handle this.

Comment: Gratitude FallenAngel, this looks like it might work. In your above example admin_perm_check.perm_name, is perm_name a parameter that's passed in your custom_params? If so, I'm not sure from your example how you are referencing it within the context processor for use in custom_params?  Thanks for your help

Comment: I guess full example is better, I will update to write full code for you to see...

Comment: Fantastic, I think I have it working now. Just so I'm clear.. what is the lazy / lambda here for? lazy(lambda: myCustomPermChecker(), myCustomPermChecker)(),

Comment: Lazy objects and methods are evaluated when they are called. You can read [more about lazy objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). I also add import for lazy to my anwser. You can check it from django code too.

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting I will read up on that. I am struggling to pass the request object through to myCustomPermChecker.. how should that be done?

Comment: You can pass any number of parameters when you define your `lazy` class calls in `'admin_perm_check': lazy(lambda: MyCustomPermChecker(request)...` and handle them in `class.__init__`

Comment: Excellent, we are up and running! You are a Gentleman and a scholar. MAny Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to evaluate `check_permission('Restrictedarea')` then do it in the view function and pass the evaluated result in the template.

The [djangobook](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html) says (in Chapter 4: Templates, in Philosophies and Limitations section) -

> Business logic should be separated from presentation logic. Django’s
>   developers see a template system as a tool that controls presentation
>   and presentation-related logic – and that’s it. The template system
>   shouldn’t support functionality that goes beyond this basic goal.
>
> For that reason, it’s impossible to call Python code directly within
>   Django templates. All “programming” is fundamentally limited to the
>   scope of what template tags can do. It is possible to write custom
>   template tags that do arbitrary things, but the out-of-the-box Django
>   template tags intentionally do not allow for arbitrary Python code
>   execution.

And if need to write custom tags check these links:

- [Writing a Template Tag in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200548/writing-a-template-tag-in-django)
- [Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: Thank you Rupak, I thought of doing it this way but the permission check is for an included 'links' template which will appear in several different views. I thought this would be bad because I would have to evaluate each permission in every view?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to evaluate the function once and use the results for other cases. But I saw when a django project uses its auth framework, the project itself uses the method `user.is_authenticated()` each time when authentication required.